# Can a search bar be used with uitableview with static cells?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, static, uisearchbar

I have an app that is a tab bar layout with 5 tableviews that I have created through interface builder. All the cells for the tableviews are static that I have then linked to Viewcontroller scenes that display what I want again all through interface builder. I was wondering if there is a way to have a search bar implemented that can search through these static cells or would i have to set up an array to hold the the pages. I'm a little lost with this as I have found search bar tutorials but they all apply to arrays with data as far as I can tell. 
I'm using Xcode 4.3 iOS 5.1 etc. all up to date.

Thanks
J